# how to take out strings based on space?

Tags: r

For example, I have a string like (abc) abc (def) def, I wanna take everything out based on the space. 
I know I need to use stringr package, but I dont know which command exactly. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely what `strsplit` (string-split) is intended for.  You can split the string on the space to get 4 individual strings.  The result is a `list`, but we can use `unlist` to coerce it into a character vector.

```
> ABCs <- "(abc) abc (def) def"
> length(ABCs)
[1] 1

> newVec <- unlist(strsplit(ABCs, split = "\\s"))
> newVec
[1] "(abc)" "abc"   "(def)" "def"  
> length(newVec)
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

```
gsub(" ","","(abc) abc (def) def")
[1] "(abc)abc(def)def"
```